# ajax error when returning json value using asp c#

Tags: c#, json, ajax

Hi I am getting an error when my webservice return a json string format.

```
[{
    "name": "Process Time - FCP",
    "color": "#7E57C2",
    "yAxis": 0,
    "data": []
 }, {
    "name": "Process Time - IP Lot",
    "color": "#F8BBD0",
    "yAxis": 0,
    "data": [{
        "x": 0,
        "low": "6/18/2018 10:04:47 AM",
        "high": "6/19/2018 8:19:48 PM",
        "lid": "AQ76951.1",
        "pname": "AD7740KRMCU-T0Z",
        "tmp": "TFCLASS_A1",
        "ptime": "34.25 Hours ",
        "asp": "-1"
    }, {
        "x": 43,
        "low": "6/21/2018 9:25:11 PM",
        "high": "6/21/2018 9:55:11 PM",
        "lid": "AQ74574.1",
        "pname": "ADF4159CCPT-T0JMPZ",
        "tmp": "NA",
        "ptime": "15.71 Hours ",
        "asp": "0"
    }]
 }, {
    "name": "Setup Type 1",
    "color": "#E040FB",
    "yAxis": 0,
    "data": [{
        "x": 0,
        "low": "6/19/2018 8:19:48 PM",
        "high": "6/19/2018 9:19:48 PM",
        "lid": "AQ76478.1",
        "pname": "AD7740YRMCU-T0Z",
        "tmp": "NA",
        "ptime": "34.25 Hours ",
        "asp": "9"
    }, {
        "x": 9,
        "low": "6/19/2018 6:35:23 PM",
        "high": "6/19/2018 7:35:23 PM",
        "lid": "AQ77515.1",
        "pname": "AD7730BRWCU-T0Z",
        "tmp": "NA",
        "ptime": "34.09 Hours ",
        "asp": "11"
    }, {
        "x": 10,
        "low": "6/20/2018 12:04:09 AM",
        "high": "6/20/2018 1:04:09 AM",
        "lid": "AQ76477.1",
        "pname": "AD7740YRMCU-T0Z",
        "tmp": "NA",
        "ptime": "36.82 Hours ",
        "asp": "9"
    }, {
        "x": 14,
        "low": "6/19/2018 1:10:12 PM",
        "high": "6/19/2018 2:10:12 PM",
        "lid": "AQ76481.1",
        "pname": "AD7740YRMCU-T0Z",
        "tmp": "NA",
        "ptime": "35.45 Hours ",
        "asp": "9"
    }, {
        "x": 27,
        "low": "6/22/2018 8:31:52 AM",
        "high": "6/22/2018 9:31:52 AM",
        "lid": "AQ76583.1",
        "pname": "AD8222BCPCT-T0Z",
        "tmp": "NA",
        "ptime": "5.32 Hours ",
        "asp": "9"
    }]
 }, {
    "name": "Setup Type 2",
    "color": "#1bf7e5",
    "yAxis": 0,
    "data": [{
        "x": 1,
        "low": "6/21/2018 5:51:58 AM",
        "high": "6/21/2018 8:51:58 AM",
        "lid": "AQ76553.1",
        "pname": "AD5262BRUCU-T050Z",
        "tmp": "NA",
        "ptime": "34.59 Hours ",
        "asp": "9"
    }, {
        "x": 24,
        "low": "6/20/2018 10:04:47 AM",
        "high": "6/20/2018 1:04:47 PM",
        "lid": "R_06/15/18_19",
        "pname": "AD8345ARECU-T0Z",
        "tmp": "NA",
        "ptime": "2.75 Hours ",
        "asp": "2"
    }, {
        "x": 43,
        "low": "6/18/2018 10:05:24 AM",
        "high": "6/18/2018 1:05:24 PM",
        "lid": "AQ74565.1",
        "pname": "ADF4159CCPT-T0JMPZ",
        "tmp": "NA",
        "ptime": "15.55 Hours ",
        "asp": "0"
    }]
 }, {
    "name": "Setup Type 2.5",
    "color": "#00796B",
    "yAxis": 0,
    "data": [{
        "x": 28,
        "low": "6/21/2018 12:33:51 AM",
        "high": "6/21/2018 7:03:51 AM",
        "lid": "AQ76651.1",
        "pname": "ADN8831ACPC7-T1Z",
        "tmp": "NA",
        "ptime": "27.78 Hours ",
        "asp": "9"
    }]
 }, {
    "name": "Setup Type 3",
    "color": "#D50000",
    "yAxis": 0,
    "data": [{
        "x": 5,
        "low": "6/21/2018 12:16:14 PM",
        "high": "6/21/2018 7:16:14 PM",
        "lid": "T_06/15/18_810",
        "pname": "ADM2209EARUCU-T0Z",
        "tmp": "NA",
        "ptime": "8.34 Hours ",
        "asp": "9"
    }, {
        "x": 42,
        "low": "6/19/2018 9:05:02 PM",
        "high": "6/20/2018 4:05:02 AM",
        "lid": "AQ76643.1",
        "pname": "ADL5904ACPC7-T0N1Z",
        "tmp": "NA",
        "ptime": "25.37 Hours ",
        "asp": "9"
    }]
 }, {
    "name": "Cold",
    "color": "#2196F3",
    "pointWidth": 5,
    "pointPadding": 0.4,
    "pointPlacement": -0.3,
    "yAxis": 0,
    "data": [{
        "x": 36,
        "low": "6/24/2018 7:45:19 AM",
        "high": "6/24/2018 4:01:42 PM",
        "lid": "AQ72455.1",
        "pname": "ADF4159CCPT-T0JMPZ",
        "tmp": "TFCLASS_C3",
        "ptime": "8.27 Hours ",
        "asp": "0"
    }, {
        "x": 36,
        "low": "6/18/2018 10:04:47 AM",
        "high": "6/18/2018 5:55:11 PM",
        "lid": "AQ74561.1",
        "pname": "ADF4159CCPT-T0JMPZ",
        "tmp": "TFCLASS_C3",
        "ptime": "7.84 Hours ",
        "asp": "-1"
    }, {
        "x": 36,
        "low": "6/19/2018 3:04:00 AM",
        "high": "6/19/2018 11:39:58 AM",
        "lid": "AQ74564.1",
        "pname": "ADF4159CCPT-T0JMPZ",
        "tmp": "TFCLASS_C3",
        "ptime": "8.60 Hours ",
        "asp": "0"
    }, {
        "x": 36,
        "low": "6/19/2018 9:15:56 PM",
        "high": "6/20/2018 5:39:54 AM",
        "lid": "AQ74566.1",
        "pname": "ADF4159CCPT-T0JMPZ",
        "tmp": "TFCLASS_C3",
        "ptime": "8.40 Hours ",
        "asp": "0"
    }, {
        "x": 36,
        "low": "6/18/2018 6:25:11 PM",
        "high": "6/19/2018 2:34:00 AM",
        "lid": "AQ74567.1",
        "pname": "ADF4159CCPT-T0JMPZ",
        "tmp": "TFCLASS_C3",
        "ptime": "8.15 Hours ",
        "asp": "0"
    }, {
        "x": 36,
        "low": "6/20/2018 2:59:46 PM",
        "high": "6/20/2018 11:19:50 PM",
        "lid": "AQ74568.1",
        "pname": "ADF4159CCPT-T0JMPZ",
        "tmp": "TFCLASS_C3",
        "ptime": "8.33 Hours ",
        "asp": "0"
    }, {
        "x": 36,
        "low": "6/20/2018 11:49:50 PM",
        "high": "6/21/2018 8:06:32 AM",
        "lid": "AQ74569.1",
        "pname": "ADF4159CCPT-T0JMPZ",
        "tmp": "TFCLASS_C3",
        "ptime": "8.28 Hours ",
        "asp": "0"
    }, {
        "x": 36,
        "low": "6/21/2018 8:36:32 AM",
        "high": "6/21/2018 5:00:43 PM",
        "lid": "AQ74570.1",
        "pname": "ADF4159CCPT-T0JMPZ",
        "tmp": "TFCLASS_C3",
        "ptime": "8.40 Hours ",
        "asp": "0"
    }, {
        "x": 36,
        "low": "6/21/2018 5:30:43 PM",
        "high": "6/22/2018 1:56:28 AM",
        "lid": "AQ74571.1",
        "pname": "ADF4159CCPT-T0JMPZ",
        "tmp": "TFCLASS_C3",
        "ptime": "8.43 Hours ",
        "asp": "0"
    }, {
        "x": 36,
        "low": "6/22/2018 2:26:28 AM",
        "high": "6/22/2018 10:43:10 AM",
        "lid": "AQ74572.1",
        "pname": "ADF4159CCPT-T0JMPZ",
        "tmp": "TFCLASS_C3",
        "ptime": "8.28 Hours ",
        "asp": "0"
    }, {
        "x": 36,
        "low": "6/22/2018 11:13:10 AM",
        "high": "6/22/2018 7:28:49 PM",
        "lid": "AQ74573.1",
        "pname": "ADF4159CCPT-T0JMPZ",
        "tmp": "TFCLASS_C3",
        "ptime": "8.26 Hours ",
        "asp": "0"
    }, {
        "x": 36,
        "low": "6/22/2018 7:58:49 PM",
        "high": "6/23/2018 4:26:09 AM",
        "lid": "AQ74574.1",
        "pname": "ADF4159CCPT-T0JMPZ",
        "tmp": "TFCLASS_C3",
        "ptime": "8.46 Hours ",
        "asp": "0"
    }, {
        "x": 36,
        "low": "6/23/2018 4:56:09 AM",
        "high": "6/23/2018 1:24:07 PM",
        "lid": "AQ74575.1",
        "pname": "ADF4159CCPT-T0JMPZ",
        "tmp": "TFCLASS_C3",
        "ptime": "8.47 Hours ",
        "asp": "0"
    }, {
        "x": 36,
        "low": "6/19/2018 12:09:58 PM",
        "high": "6/19/2018 8:45:56 PM",
        "lid": "AQ74577.1",
        "pname": "ADF4159CCPT-T0JMPZ",
        "tmp": "TFCLASS_C3",
        "ptime": "8.60 Hours ",
        "asp": "0"
    }, {
        "x": 36,
        "low": "6/24/2018 8:03:06 PM",
        "high": "6/25/2018 1:15:03 PM",
        "lid": "AQ74579.1",
        "pname": "ADF4159CCPT-T0JMPZ",
        "tmp": "TFCLASS_C3",
        "ptime": "17.20 Hours ",
        "asp": "0"
    }, {
        "x": 36,
        "low": "6/25/2018 1:45:03 PM",
        "high": "6/26/2018 6:56:59 AM",
        "lid": "AQ74581.1",
        "pname": "ADF4159CCPT-T0JMPZ",
        "tmp": "TFCLASS_C3",
        "ptime": "17.20 Hours ",
        "asp": "0"
    }, {
        "x": 36,
        "low": "6/23/2018 1:54:07 PM",
        "high": "6/23/2018 10:20:43 PM",
        "lid": "AQ74582.1",
        "pname": "ADF4159CCPT-T0JMPZ",
        "tmp": "TFCLASS_C3",
        "ptime": "8.44 Hours ",
        "asp": "0"
    }, {
        "x": 36,
        "low": "6/20/2018 6:09:54 AM",
        "high": "6/20/2018 2:29:46 PM",
        "lid": "AQ74585.1",
        "pname": "ADF4159CCPT-T0JMPZ",
        "tmp": "TFCLASS_C3",
        "ptime": "8.33 Hours ",
        "asp": "0"
    }, {
        "x": 36,
        "low": "6/23/2018 10:50:43 PM",
        "high": "6/24/2018 7:15:19 AM",
        "lid": "AQ74589.1",
        "pname": "ADF4159CCPT-T0JMPZ",
        "tmp": "TFCLASS_C3",
        "ptime": "8.41 Hours ",
        "asp": "0"
    }, {
        "x": 36,
        "low": "6/30/2018 2:02:49 AM",
        "high": "6/30/2018 7:14:45 PM",
        "lid": "AQ76993.1",
        "pname": "ADF4159CCPT-T0JMPZ",
        "tmp": "TFCLASS_C3",
        "ptime": "17.20 Hours ",
        "asp": "11"
    }, {
        "x": 36,
        "low": "6/30/2018 7:44:45 PM",
        "high": "7/1/2018 12:56:42 PM",
        "lid": "AQ76995.1",
        "pname": "ADF4159CCPT-T0JMPZ",
        "tmp": "TFCLASS_C3",
        "ptime": "17.20 Hours ",
        "asp": "11"
    }, {
        "x": 36,
        "low": "7/1/2018 1:26:42 PM",
        "high": "7/2/2018 6:38:38 AM",
        "lid": "AQ76997.1",
        "pname": "ADF4159CCPT-T0JMPZ",
        "tmp": "TFCLASS_C3",
        "ptime": "17.20 Hours ",
        "asp": "11"
    }, {
        "x": 36,
        "low": "7/2/2018 7:08:38 AM",
        "high": "7/3/2018 12:20:35 AM",
        "lid": "AQ76999.1",
        "pname": "ADF4159CCPT-T0JMPZ",
        "tmp": "TFCLASS_C3",
        "ptime": "17.20 Hours ",
        "asp": "11"
    }, {
        "x": 36,
        "low": "6/26/2018 7:26:59 AM",
        "high": "6/26/2018 4:02:58 PM",
        "lid": "AQ77000.1",
        "pname": "ADF4159CCPT-T0JMPZ",
        "tmp": "TFCLASS_C3",
        "ptime": "8.60 Hours ",
        "asp": "11"
    }]
 }, {
    "name": "Ambient",
    "color": "#FBC02D",
    "pointWidth": 5,
    "pointPadding": 0.4,
    "pointPlacement": -0.3,
    "yAxis": 0,
    "data": [{
        "x": 0,
        "low": "6/19/2018 9:19:48 PM",
        "high": "6/21/2018 7:34:45 AM",
        "lid": "AQ76478.1",
        "pname": "AD7740YRMCU-T0Z",
        "tmp": "TFCLASS_A1",
        "ptime": "34.25 Hours ",
        "asp": "9"
    },{
        "x": 29,
        "low": "6/21/2018 7:05:58 PM",
        "high": "6/22/2018 9:12:35 AM",
        "lid": "AQ75243.1",
        "pname": "ADF7250BCPCT-TNZ",
        "tmp": "TFCLASS_A1",
        "ptime": "14.11 Hours ",
        "asp": "0"
    }, {
        "x": 29,
        "low": "6/20/2018 4:34:29 PM",
        "high": "6/21/2018 2:03:41 AM",
        "lid": "AQ76554.1",
        "pname": "AD57/013-0CPCU-T0Z",
        "tmp": "TFCLASS_A1",
        "ptime": "9.49 Hours ",
        "asp": "9"
    }, {
        "x": 29,
        "low": "6/21/2018 5:03:41 AM",
        "high": "6/21/2018 12:35:58 PM",
        "lid": "AQ76636.1",
        "pname": "ADF4355BCPT-T0JTUZ",
        "tmp": "TFCLASS_A1",
        "ptime": "7.54 Hours ",
        "asp": "9"
    }, {
        "x": 29,
        "low": "6/22/2018 9:42:35 AM",
        "high": "6/23/2018 3:39:16 AM",
        "lid": "AQ77029.1",
        "pname": "ADF7250BCPCT-TNZ",
        "tmp": "TFCLASS_A1",
        "ptime": "17.94 Hours ",
        "asp": "11"
    }, {
        "x": 30,
        "low": "6/19/2018 12:44:59 AM",
        "high": "6/19/2018 5:38:51 PM",
        "lid": "AQ74579.1",
        "pname": "ADF4159CCPT-T0JMPZ",
        "tmp": "TFCLASS_A1",
        "ptime": "16.15 Hours ",
        "asp": "0"
    }, {
        "x": 30,
        "low": "6/21/2018 1:59:23 PM",
        "high": "6/22/2018 6:08:14 AM",
        "lid": "AQ76995.1",
        "pname": "ADF4159CCPT-T0JMPZ",
        "tmp": "TFCLASS_A1",
        "ptime": "16.15 Hours ",
        "asp": "11"
    }, {
        "x": 30,
        "low": "6/22/2018 6:38:14 AM",
        "high": "6/22/2018 10:47:06 PM",
        "lid": "AQ76999.1",
        "pname": "ADF4159CCPT-T0JMPZ",
        "tmp": "TFCLASS_A1",
        "ptime": "16.15 Hours ",
        "asp": "11"
    }, {
        "x": 30,
        "low": "6/21/2018 2:51:31 AM",
        "high": "6/21/2018 1:29:23 PM",
        "lid": "AQ77001.1",
        "pname": "ADF4159CCPT-T0JMPZ",
        "tmp": "TFCLASS_A1",
        "ptime": "10.63 Hours ",
        "asp": "11"
    }, {
        "x": 33,
        "low": "6/21/2018 1:34:10 PM",
        "high": "6/22/2018 1:36:51 PM",
        "lid": "AQ77511.1",
        "pname": "ADF4118BRUCU-T0WZ",
        "tmp": "TFCLASS_A1",
        "ptime": "24.04 Hours ",
        "asp": "11"
    }, {
        "x": 33,
        "low": "6/21/2018 12:18:42 AM",
        "high": "6/21/2018 10:34:10 AM",
        "lid": "AQ77592.1",
        "pname": "ADF4118BRUCU-T0Z",
        "tmp": "TFCLASS_A1",
        "ptime": "10.26 Hours ",
        "asp": "11"
    }, {
        "x": 34,
        "low": "6/18/2018 10:04:47 AM",
        "high": "6/18/2018 9:13:11 PM",
        "lid": "AQ75059.1",
        "pname": "ADL5205ACPC7-T0Z",
        "tmp": "TFCLASS_A1",
        "ptime": "11.14 Hours ",
        "asp": "-1"
    }, {
        "x": 34,
        "low": "6/18/2018 9:43:11 PM",
        "high": "6/19/2018 2:29:11 PM",
        "lid": "AQ76638.1",
        "pname": "ADL5205ACPC7-T0Z",
        "tmp": "TFCLASS_A1",
        "ptime": "16.77 Hours ",
        "asp": "9"
    }, {
        "x": 34,
        "low": "6/20/2018 9:38:27 AM",
        "high": "6/20/2018 3:02:29 PM",
        "lid": "AQ77226.1",
        "pname": "ADL5566ACPC7-T0Z",
        "tmp": "TFCLASS_A1",
        "ptime": "5.40 Hours ",
        "asp": "11"
    }, {
        "x": 34,
        "low": "6/19/2018 8:59:11 PM",
        "high": "6/20/2018 6:38:27 AM",
        "lid": "AQ77372.1",
        "pname": "ADF4360-3BCPCT-T1Z",
        "tmp": "TFCLASS_A1",
        "ptime": "9.65 Hours ",
        "asp": "11"
    }, {
        "x": 35,
        "low": "6/21/2018 4:34:32 PM",
        "high": "6/22/2018 10:39:17 AM",
        "lid": "AQ77227.1",
        "pname": "ADL5903ACPC7-T0Z",
        "tmp": "TFCLASS_A1",
        "ptime": "18.08 Hours ",
        "asp": "11"
    }, {
        "x": 35,
        "low": "6/20/2018 10:02:29 PM",
        "high": "6/21/2018 4:04:32 PM",
        "lid": "AQ77228.1",
        "pname": "ADL5903ACPC7-T0Z",
        "tmp": "TFCLASS_A1",
        "ptime": "18.03 Hours ",
        "asp": "11"
    }, {
        "x": 39,
        "low": "6/19/2018 11:02:23 PM",
        "high": "6/20/2018 9:42:57 AM",
        "lid": "AQ73951.1",
        "pname": "ADF4150HVBCPCT-T0Z",
        "tmp": "TFCLASS_A1",
        "ptime": "10.68 Hours ",
        "asp": "0"
    }, {
        "x": 39,
        "low": "6/18/2018 10:04:47 AM",
        "high": "6/19/2018 8:02:23 PM",
        "lid": "AQ73957.1",
        "pname": "ADF7023-JBCPT-T0JZ",
        "tmp": "TFCLASS_A1",
        "ptime": "33.96 Hours ",
        "asp": "-1"
    }, {
        "x": 39,
        "low": "6/20/2018 10:12:57 AM",
        "high": "6/21/2018 1:56:19 PM",
        "lid": "AQ74004.1",
        "pname": "ADF4150HVBCPCT-T0Z",
        "tmp": "TFCLASS_A1",
        "ptime": "27.72 Hours ",
        "asp": "0"
    }, {
        "x": 40,
        "low": "6/18/2018 4:21:36 PM",
        "high": "6/19/2018 12:52:38 AM",
        "lid": "AQ72455.1",
        "pname": "ADF4159CCPT-T0JMPZ",
        "tmp": "TFCLASS_A1",
        "ptime": "7.77 Hours ",
        "asp": "0"
    }, {
        "x": 40,
        "low": "6/19/2018 1:22:38 AM",
        "high": "6/19/2018 5:31:29 PM",
        "lid": "AQ74581.1",
        "pname": "ADF4159CCPT-T0JMPZ",
        "tmp": "TFCLASS_A1",
        "ptime": "16.15 Hours ",
        "asp": "0"
    }, {
        "x": 40,
        "low": "6/21/2018 11:29:10 AM",
        "high": "6/22/2018 3:38:01 AM",
        "lid": "AQ76993.1",
        "pname": "ADF4159CCPT-T0JMPZ",
        "tmp": "TFCLASS_A1",
        "ptime": "16.15 Hours ",
        "asp": "11"
    }, {
        "x": 40,
        "low": "6/22/2018 4:08:01 AM",
        "high": "6/22/2018 8:16:53 PM",
        "lid": "AQ76997.1",
        "pname": "ADF4159CCPT-T0JMPZ",
        "tmp": "TFCLASS_A1",
        "ptime": "16.15 Hours ",
        "asp": "11"
    }, {
        "x": 43,
        "low": "6/18/2018 10:04:47 AM",
        "high": "6/18/2018 10:05:24 AM",
        "lid": "AQ77187.1",
        "pname": "ADF4150BCPCT-T0Z",
        "tmp": "TQCLASS_A1",
        "ptime": "0.01 Hour ",
        "asp": "-1"
    }]
 }, {
    "name": "Hot",
    "color": "#FF3D00",
    "pointWidth": 5,
    "pointPadding": 0.4,
    "pointPlacement": -0.3,
    "yAxis": 0,
    "data": [{
        "x": 30,
        "low": "6/18/2018 10:04:47 AM",
        "high": "6/19/2018 12:14:59 AM",
        "lid": "AQ74564.1",
        "pname": "ADF4159CCPT-T0JMPZ",
        "tmp": "TFCLASS_H2",
        "ptime": "14.17 Hours ",
        "asp": "-1"
    }, {
        "x": 31,
        "low": "6/22/2018 7:37:20 PM",
        "high": "6/23/2018 4:18:15 PM",
        "lid": "AQ76627.1",
        "pname": "ADF4193CCPC7-T1Z",
        "tmp": "TFCLASS_H2",
        "ptime": "20.68 Hours ",
        "asp": "9"
    }, {
        "x": 31,
        "low": "6/21/2018 10:38:18 PM",
        "high": "6/22/2018 7:07:20 PM",
        "lid": "AQ76628.1",
        "pname": "ADF4193CCPC7-T1Z",
        "tmp": "TFCLASS_H2",
        "ptime": "20.48 Hours ",
        "asp": "9"
    }, {
        "x": 31,
        "low": "6/21/2018 1:03:57 AM",
        "high": "6/21/2018 10:08:18 PM",
        "lid": "AQ76629.1",
        "pname": "ADF4193CCPC7-T1Z",
        "tmp": "TFCLASS_H2",
        "ptime": "20.32 Hours ",
        "asp": "0"
    }, {
        "x": 37,
        "low": "6/18/2018 7:13:48 PM",
        "high": "6/19/2018 10:50:23 AM",
        "lid": "AQ74566.1",
        "pname": "ADF4159CCPT-T0JMPZ",
        "tmp": "TFCLASS_H2",
        "ptime": "15.61 Hours ",
        "asp": "0"
    }, {
        "x": 37,
        "low": "6/20/2018 3:19:21 AM",
        "high": "6/20/2018 6:42:26 PM",
        "lid": "AQ74569.1",
        "pname": "ADF4159CCPT-T0JMPZ",
        "tmp": "TFCLASS_H2",
        "ptime": "15.38 Hours ",
        "asp": "0"
    }, {
        "x": 37,
        "low": "6/20/2018 7:12:26 PM",
        "high": "6/21/2018 10:52:22 AM",
        "lid": "AQ74571.1",
        "pname": "ADF4159CCPT-T0JMPZ",
        "tmp": "TFCLASS_H2",
        "ptime": "15.67 Hours ",
        "asp": "0"
    }, {
        "x": 37,
        "low": "6/21/2018 11:22:22 AM",
        "high": "6/22/2018 2:43:30 AM",
        "lid": "AQ74573.1",
        "pname": "ADF4159CCPT-T0JMPZ",
        "tmp": "TFCLASS_H2",
        "ptime": "15.35 Hours ",
        "asp": "0"
    }, {
        "x": 37,
        "low": "6/22/2018 3:13:30 AM",
        "high": "6/22/2018 6:57:32 PM",
        "lid": "AQ74575.1",
        "pname": "ADF4159CCPT-T0JMPZ",
        "tmp": "TFCLASS_H2",
        "ptime": "15.73 Hours ",
        "asp": "0"
    }, {
        "x": 37,
        "low": "6/18/2018 10:04:47 AM",
        "high": "6/18/2018 6:43:48 PM",
        "lid": "AQ74577.1",
        "pname": "ADF4159CCPT-T0JMPZ",
        "tmp": "TFCLASS_H2",
        "ptime": "8.65 Hours ",
        "asp": "-1"
    }, {
        "x": 37,
        "low": "6/23/2018 11:35:18 AM",
        "high": "6/24/2018 7:33:06 PM",
        "lid": "AQ74579.1",
        "pname": "ADF4159CCPT-T0JMPZ",
        "tmp": "TFCLASS_H2",
        "ptime": "31.96 Hours ",
        "asp": "0"
    }, {
        "x": 37,
        "low": "6/19/2018 11:20:23 AM",
        "high": "6/20/2018 2:49:21 AM",
        "lid": "AQ74585.1",
        "pname": "ADF4159CCPT-T0JMPZ",
        "tmp": "TFCLASS_H2",
        "ptime": "15.48 Hours ",
        "asp": "0"
    }, {
        "x": 37,
        "low": "6/22/2018 7:27:32 PM",
        "high": "6/23/2018 11:05:18 AM",
        "lid": "AQ74589.1",
        "pname": "ADF4159CCPT-T0JMPZ",
        "tmp": "TFCLASS_H2",
        "ptime": "15.63 Hours ",
        "asp": "0"
    }, {
        "x": 37,
        "low": "6/28/2018 4:09:48 AM",
        "high": "6/29/2018 12:07:36 PM",
        "lid": "AQ76993.1",
        "pname": "ADF4159CCPT-T0JMPZ",
        "tmp": "TFCLASS_H2",
        "ptime": "31.96 Hours ",
        "asp": "11"
    }, {
        "x": 37,
        "low": "6/29/2018 12:37:36 PM",
        "high": "6/30/2018 8:35:25 PM",
        "lid": "AQ76997.1",
        "pname": "ADF4159CCPT-T0JMPZ",
        "tmp": "TFCLASS_H2",
        "ptime": "31.96 Hours ",
        "asp": "11"
    }, {
        "x": 37,
        "low": "6/24/2018 8:03:06 PM",
        "high": "6/25/2018 12:02:01 PM",
        "lid": "AQ77000.1",
        "pname": "ADF4159CCPT-T0JMPZ",
        "tmp": "TFCLASS_H2",
        "ptime": "15.98 Hours ",
        "asp": "11"
    }, {
        "x": 43,
        "low": "6/20/2018 1:55:06 PM",
        "high": "6/21/2018 5:32:06 AM",
        "lid": "AQ74570.1",
        "pname": "ADF4159CCPT-T0JMPZ",
        "tmp": "TFCLASS_H2",
        "ptime": "15.62 Hours ",
        "asp": "0"
    }, {
        "x": 43,
        "low": "6/21/2018 6:02:06 AM",
        "high": "6/21/2018 9:25:11 PM",
        "lid": "AQ74572.1",
        "pname": "ADF4159CCPT-T0JMPZ",
        "tmp": "TFCLASS_H2",
        "ptime": "15.38 Hours ",
        "asp": "0"
    }, {
        "x": 43,
        "low": "6/21/2018 9:55:11 PM",
        "high": "6/22/2018 1:38:03 PM",
        "lid": "AQ74574.1",
        "pname": "ADF4159CCPT-T0JMPZ",
        "tmp": "TFCLASS_H2",
        "ptime": "15.71 Hours ",
        "asp": "0"
    }, {
        "x": 43,
        "low": "6/23/2018 10:12:02 PM",
        "high": "6/25/2018 6:09:51 AM",
        "lid": "AQ74581.1",
        "pname": "ADF4159CCPT-T0JMPZ",
        "tmp": "TFCLASS_H2",
        "ptime": "31.96 Hours ",
        "asp": "0"
    }, {
        "x": 43,
        "low": "6/22/2018 2:08:03 PM",
        "high": "6/23/2018 5:49:32 AM",
        "lid": "AQ74582.1",
        "pname": "ADF4159CCPT-T0JMPZ",
        "tmp": "TFCLASS_H2",
        "ptime": "15.69 Hours ",
        "asp": "0"
    }, {
        "x": 43,
        "low": "6/19/2018 5:53:16 AM",
        "high": "6/19/2018 9:25:45 PM",
        "lid": "AQ74584.1",
        "pname": "ADF4159CCPT-T0JMPZ",
        "tmp": "TFCLASS_H2",
        "ptime": "15.54 Hours ",
        "asp": "0"
    }, {
        "x": 43,
        "low": "6/28/2018 7:29:19 PM",
        "high": "6/30/2018 3:27:07 AM",
        "lid": "AQ76995.1",
        "pname": "ADF4159CCPT-T0JMPZ",
        "tmp": "TFCLASS_H2",
        "ptime": "31.96 Hours ",
        "asp": "11"
    }, {
        "x": 43,
        "low": "6/25/2018 6:39:51 AM",
        "high": "6/26/2018 3:04:30 AM",
        "lid": "AQ77007.1",
        "pname": "ADF4159CCPT-T0JMPZ",
        "tmp": "TFCLASS_H2",
        "ptime": "20.41 Hours ",
        "asp": "11"
    }]
 }, {
    "name": "TCVOS & Postburn",
    "color": "#00BCD4",
    "pointWidth": 5,
    "pointPadding": 0.4,
    "pointPlacement": -0.3,
    "yAxis": 0,
    "data": []
 }, {
    "name": "Brand",
    "color": "#607D8B",
    "pointWidth": 5,
    "pointPadding": 0.4,
    "pointPlacement": -0.3,
    "yAxis": 0,
    "data": []
 }]
```

For some users, this format works fine. But for some, it throws an error.

Following is my AJAX call code

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../tab_items.asmx/sched_chart_backend",
        data: '{ coordinator: "' + coordinator + '", date_loaded: "' + date_loaded + '"}',
        contentType: "application/json",
        beforeSend: function () {
            document.getElementById("div_4").className = "cssload-container";
            document.getElementById("div_4").innerHTML = "<div class='cssload-double-torus'></div>";
            document.getElementById("sched_chart").style.display = 'none';


        },
        complete: function () {
            //alert("sended");
            document.getElementById("div_4").innerHTML = "<img src='Images/round_ck.png' class='img_cross_ck'/>";
            document.getElementById("div_4").className = "";
            document.getElementById("sched_chart").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("tab_5").style.display = 'block';
        },
        success: function (r) {
            alert(r);
            //schedule_charts_g(r.d[0],r.d[1],r.d[2],r.d[3],r.d[4]);    
            //document.getElementById("legendary").innerHTML = r.d[5];
            //metrics_amds();

        },
        error: function (er) {
            alert("error");
            document.getElementById("tab_4").style.display = 'none';
           // metrics_amds();
        }

    });
```

Comment: What's the error, and where?

Comment: when i don't return the json string format there is no error. but when i return the json string format the error occur

Comment: this maybe silly but, did you try to log `er` when an error occurs? So an error occurs when you return json but doesn't when you don't? I don't understand what you mean when you say "when i return the json string format the error occur"

Comment: for example i return a string = "1" it will alert "1" but when i return the jsong string format error happen

Comment: this solve my problem
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151987/can-i-set-an-unlimited-length-for-maxjsonlength-in-web-config